# How to get values of injected beans in a common class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm using Springboot to develop a web server and I need to add some custom configurations for it. So I put the config into `resources/application.properties` as below:

```
apple.price=1
```

In some function I need to get the config.

```
class MyObj {
    @Value
    private int applePrice;
}
```

This is not working because `MyObj` is not managed by Springboot.

But I couldn't add any annotation like `@Component` for the class `MyObj` because the objects of `MyObj` is initialized manually: `MyObj obj = new MyObj();`

So it seems that I need to get the injected bean in an unmanaged object.

I'm a Springboot newbie, please help me on this issue.

Comment: ..add `@Component` annotation to where it "is manually initialized" ..and set it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have access to the application context or other beans, you can keep static reference to `AutowireCapableSpringBeanFactory` to manually autowire manually created objects. You could do it as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73898684/17795888), for example.

Then autowire the instances like this:

```
MyObj obj = new MyObj();
ApplicationContextHolder.autowireBean(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a spring managed bean and inject property into that bean. Then you can pass it as a constructor argument to your `MyObj`.

Here is the example:

```java
@Component // will be instantiated by Spring as a singleton bean
public class MyObjFactory {

    @Value("${apple.price}")
    private int applePrice;

    public MyObj newMyObject() {
        return new MyObj(applePrice);
    }
}
```

Remember that you should not manually create `MyObjFactory` using the `new` operator. Spring instantiates classes marked as `@Component` during context creation. So you need to inject that factory where you want to use it. You can read more about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html